# How do I get AutoMapper to populate my viewmodel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

Code sample for my question:

```
IList<TestDataAnimal> testDataFromDb = this.db.TestDataAnimals.Include(t => t.TestType).Include(t => t.Visit).Include(t => t.Visit.Patient).ToList();

Mapper.CreateMap<TestDataAnimal, TestDataAnimalViewModel>();

IList<TestDataAnimalViewModel> viewModelList = Mapper.Map<IList<TestDataAnimal>, IList<TestDataAnimalViewModel>>(testDataFromDb);
```

In the above code, `testDataFromDb` returns all the data that I need. So far, so good... I know I'm getting all the right data from the database. The problem is `viewModelList` is not populated with data from `Visit.Patient`.

My viewmodel has properties for `FirstName`, `LastName`, `MRN`, `DOB`, and `PatientId`. With the exception of `PatientId`, which is named `Id` in `Visit.Patient`, the property names match in the domain objects and viewmodel.

How do I get AutoMapper to populate my viewmodel properties with the values found in `Visit.Patient` ? Thanks!

SOLUTION - Added here because I can't answer my own question...

It's called flattening and I just found a video [here](http://www.dimecasts.net/Content/WatchEpisode/160)

Basically, this is what I want:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TestDataAnimal, TestDataAnimalViewModel>()
.ForMember(d => d.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Visit.Patient.FirstName));
```

Comment: Solution added to end of question...

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer.

Comment: you can also use nested mapping to preserve inner collections

Comment: @user1469655, was my pots useful for you? please, vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called flattening and I just found a video [here](http://www.dimecasts.net/Content/WatchEpisode/160)

Basically, this is what Iwant:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TestDataAnimal, TestDataAnimalViewModel>()
.ForMember(d => d.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Visit.Patient.FirstName));
```

*** Found the answer to my own question shortly after posting here but SO said I was unable to answer my own question. Now, I can't accept my own answer for a few hours.